# issue using file_get_contents with a variable as the link to target file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I'm trying to loop through an array of links, and use the file_get_contents to get the source code and take certain content from it:

```
$links = file('mysite2.txt');

foreach($links as $link) {

$f = file_get_contents("$link");
$source = $f;


if(preg_match('/<meta pro=\"(.*)\" \/>/',$source,$matches)) {
   $answer = $matches[1];

echo "$answer";
}

}
```

Now when i use $link in the `file_get_contents` (`file_get_contents("$link")`) function, the `preg_match` condition is false. Yet when i use one of the links in my_site2.txt in the `file_get_contents` (`file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/something")) it works fine.

I've even tried using a different txt file which only contains one link, which had the correct string in the source code.

Iv also tried without quotes: `file_get_contents($link)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a couple of things.

1. filenames in `$f` will contain newlines. You need to add an additional flag for `file` to prevent this:

   ```
   $links = file('mysite2.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
   ```
2. you don't need to escape double quotes in your regex.
3. are you sure that your regex needs a space before `/>`? Your regex will match `<meta pro="test" />` but not `<meta pro="test"/>`.

Comment: Right, I see. Cheers for that mate.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of $link when decalred in the foreach loop is probably an array or an object.

Try var_dump() on $link and see what is within it, this might help you to understand how to manipulate it's contents.

How is you .txt file setup?

Heres a solution:-

If you just sepreate the links like

link1,link2,link3,link4,link5

Then do

```
$links = explode( ',' , file_get_content($file) ) ;
```

Then foreach for this array

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the quotes from `$f = file_get_contents("$link");`

to make `$f = file_get_contents($link);`